# Mingw32-make exits with code 2 error on my 64-bit system

Tags: c, makefile, mingw

I need to compile and install a toolkit for a project I'm working on. However, according to the documentation the toolkit needs to be compiled using Mingw32 and I have a 64-bit system. While Mingw configures the source code without any errors or warnings, mingw32-make exits with a code 2 error.

Executing mingw-32-make throws the following errors:

```
In file included from src/SMILExtract.cpp:39:
src/smileCommon.hpp:162:16: error: ambiguating new declaration of 'long int getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)'
 DLLEXPORT long getline (char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
                ^~~~~~~
In file included from src/smileCommon.hpp:55,
             from src/SMILExtract.cpp:39:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:655:33: note: old declaration 'ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)'
__cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW ssize_t getline
                                 ^~~~~~~
In file included from src/smileLogger.hpp:73,
             from src/smileLogger.cpp:46:
src/smileCommon.hpp:162:16: error: In file included from ambiguating new declaration of 'src/configManager.hpp:43long int getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*),
             from '
DLLEXPORT long src/configManager.cpp:55:
getline (char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
            src/smileCommon.hpp:162:16: error: ambiguating new declaration of 'long int getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)    ^~~~~~~'
```

and continues to exit with error code 2 as such:

```
Makefile:1152: recipe for target 'src/libopensmile_la-SMILExtract.lo' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [src/libopensmile_la-SMILExtract.lo] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/Users/MaaikeK/openEAR'
Makefile:450: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As I understand it, this may involve casting 32-bit long variables to 64-bit long variables. However, I'm not familiar with C or C++ and am not sure how to fix it so that mingw32-make is successfully executed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like `smileCommon.hpp` defines its own version of `getline` in case the standard function is unavailable. Quick hack would be to just delete it from `smileCommon.hpp` and `.cpp` files; cleaner one is to `#ifdef` it out.

Comment: @VictorSergienko thank you, that fixed it!